# Laravel+Vuejs: v-model not connecting to app.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Code in app.js

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    data:{
        banana:''
    }
});
```

Code in master.blade.php

```
<div class="wrapper" id="app">
    <router-view></router-view> //from Vue router to display Banana.vue
</div>
```

Code in Banana.vue

```
<input type="search" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search" v-model="banana">
```

Error Message:

```
app.js:70634 [Vue warn]: Property or method "banana" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.
```

How can the banana in app.js be accessible to Banana.vue? Thank you.

Comment: `data` bound to the `$root` instance is not scoped to the encapsulated elements in order to avoid `instanced pollution`. You must reference it directly with `this.$root.$data.banana`. This isn't ideal, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="search" name="table_search" class="form-control float-right" placeholder="Search" v-model="$root.$data.banana">
```